# Windows 7 - Internet Explorer - Multiple instances of same version

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I have been hired to work with multiple clients as once using IE on Windows 7. I just want to ask if there is any way to run multiple IE's at once packed with several tabs each individually divided across them.

I would like to run each IE as separated unit for each client i am working with. One IE instance could have client A stuff and second client B etc.

I really would like to click instances on task bar to load each browser config to match current client.

EDIT: Just to clarify i am doing customer service which gives me different tools for different services. I would like to organize them in different IE windows.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need a piece of software like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and related questions for that, [tag:IeTester]

Comment: Hey! I have no administrive priviledges on machine so i can not install new software (obviously i can ask, but it might very well being high NONO)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using virtual machines for each IE instance - that way you get as "real" of an IE as possible.

Microsoft has VMs available with versions of IE 8+ and Windows 7+:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks, but it might take too long for a client to understand what is going on. 
I just want to access same tabs on each window on browser for each client